# Java Keystore Setup with .crt and .key files

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I am following a guide to set up a keystore file for a specific minecraft server plugin. The guide says I should do the following:

```
keytool -import 
-alias <tlskeyalias> 
-file cert_file.crt 
-keypass <keypassword>  
-keystore Cert.jks 
-storepass <storepassword>
```

But I have no Idea what to enter for Keypass. Could somebody tell me what to enter there? I searched Google & SO and even asked the Developer, but I wasn't able to find anything. If there is something in the internet about that, I'm sorry, I wasn't really sure what exactly to search for

Comment: It's a password. The same one used when the key with that particular alias was created.

Comment: What do you mean? The only password I define is the Storepass for the .jks Keystore File

Comment: Nevermind, I see you are importing stuff. You choose the `keypass` password yourself, though it is optional when importing a certificate.